# Include Gem Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, httparty

I'm getting a weird error when I'm trying to include a gem within my controller, below is the code i'm using in the controller and the error I get is:

```
> undefined method `include' for <CatalogController:0x00000002427b90>
```

The code returning this error is as follows:

```
require 'httparty'
require 'json'

class CatalogController < ApplicationController

    # GET /feeds
    # GET /feeds.json
    def index
      # GRAB THE URL
      include HTTParty
      base_uri 'https://www.parsehub.com/api/v2/runs'

      # PARSE THE RESPONSE

      def art
        response = self.class.get("/tnZ4F47Do9a7QeDnI6_8EKea/data?&format=json")
        @elements = response.parsed_response["image"]
        @parsed = @elements.collect { |e| e['url'] }
      end


    end

end
```

Not too sure why this error is returning?

Comment: Move `include HTTParty` out of `index`

Comment: Why do you define a method inside another?

Comment: Apologies still learning rails! :)

Comment: @Aetherus On moving the include as you suggested - I now get the following error 'undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass'?

Comment: Before you learn ruby meta programming, never define a method inside another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need include. In fact, you shouldn't even need that require. I assume this is a rails app. If you have the `httparty` gem installed via your `Gemfile`, you can simply make calls with httparty throughout your application.

Also move that `art` method outside of your index method.